# Insert missing dates in DataFrame and convert into arrays

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
Buying_date Event_date  Number_of_tickets_sold

12/11/2018  01/01/2019  2

20/01/2019  24/03/2019  1

13/11/2018  01/01/2019  3

21/12/2018  01/01/2019  2

01/01/2019  10/01/2019  4

20/02/2019  21/02/2019  2

01/03/2019  24/03/2019  3
```

Tickets are released 90 days before each event date. There are some days no one buys the tickets but I want to include every day from day 90 to day 0 in Buying_date column, and set the corresponding Number_of_tickets_sold for those days to 0.
After that, I would like to create a Numpy array of Number_of_tickets_sold for each event. So if there 10 events, there will be 10 arrays, each has 90 values.

Please help with the problem!

Array for the event on 01/01/2019:

```
np.array([0, 0 , 1, 3, 2....])
```

Answer (score 0):

Now this might get little complicated :)

Let's assume your data is in dataframe "df"

Let's create a dataframe which has combination of all event dates and 90 days past from that date

```
list_data=[pd.concat([pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(k)).repeat(90).reset_index()[0], \
pd.Series(pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(k)-datetime.timedelta(90),\
                        periods=90,freq='D')).reset_index()[0]],axis=1) for k in df.Event_Date]

my_need=pd.concat(list_data)
my_need.columns=['Event_Date','Buying_Date']
```

Convert datatype to date format

```
df['Event_Date']=df['Event_Date'].astype('datetime64')
df['Buying_Date']=df['Buying_Date'].astype('datetime64')
```

Let's merge and then fill NAs with 0

```
final=pd.merge(my_need,df,how='left')
final.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any way to put the missing dates and set the tickets sold to 0 in the original table?

Answer (score 0):

You can do, for example:

```
def resample(g, date):
    return g.reindex(pd.date_range(end=date, freq='D', periods=90)).fillna(0)

for date, g in (df["Number_of_tickets_sold"].groupby(df['Event_date'])):
    print(resample(g, date))
```

This will give you, for each event, a series of ticket sale per day, indexed by date. If you don't care for the index, you can do:

```
def resample(g, date):
    return (g.reindex(pd.date_range(end=date, freq='D', periods=90))
             .fillna(0)
             .reset_index(drop=True)
           )

pd.DataFrame({date:resample(g, date) for date,g in df["Number_of_tickets_sold"]
              .groupby(df['Event_date'])})
```

Then, you would have a dataframe like this:

```
    2019-01-01  2019-02-21  2019-03-24  2019-10-01
0          0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
1          0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
2          0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
3          0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
4          0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
5          0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
```

where the columns are daily ticket sales for each event for each day.

If you want the same format as the original data:

```
def resample(g):
    dates = pd.date_range(end=g['Event_date'][0], freq='D', periods=90)
    return g['Number_of_tickets_sold'].reindex(dates).fillna(0)

(df.set_index('Buying_date')
   .groupby('Event_date')
   .apply(resample)
   .reset_index()
)
```

would give you

```
    Event_date    level_1  Number_of_tickets_sold
0   2019-01-01 2018-10-04                     0.0
1   2019-01-01 2018-10-05                     0.0
2   2019-01-01 2018-10-06                     0.0
3   2019-01-01 2018-10-07                     0.0
4   2019-01-01 2018-10-08                     0.0
5   2019-01-01 2018-10-09                     0.0
```

where `level_1` column is the date of sale.

Comment: Hi in the new DataFrame how can I transfer Number_of_tickets_sold from my original table?

Comment: Now that's definitely something you should have mentioned in your question. Because, filling up table with missing dates is somewhat different from getting the lists.

Comment: Oh maybe I didn't make it clear. So how can I insert the missing dates and set tickets_sold to 0 in the original table? I have 10 events so it should be 10*90days = 900 rows. Truly appreciate your help.